# Password Validation using Python

Tags: python, while-loop, passwords

I am trying to make a code that validates the password you access into the program. The password should be at least 6 characters long, have 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number and 1 punctuation. This is what I have for now:

```
def main():
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter the desired password: ")
        if not password.islower(): 
            print("This is NOT a valid password.")
        elif not password.isupper(): 
            print("This is NOT a valid password.")
        elif not password.isdigit():
            print("This is NOT a valid password.")
        elif not len(password) < 6:
            print("This is NOT a valid password.")
        else:
            print("This is a valid password.")
            break
main()
```

For some reason it keeps printing that the password is not valid even if I wrote a valid one, does anyone know why is this happening?. Additionally, how can I make the code detect that there is at least 1 punctuation in the password I write? Thank you!

Comment: Try explaining, in English words, exactly what you expect each of the conditions to accomplish. For example: `if not password.islower():` what values do you expect to match this condition (and thus be invalid)? What values do you expect to *not* match this condition (such that others are checked)? Now, try verifying that. For example, you could use a different message for each of the "NOT a valid password" lines, so that you see which condition was met.

Comment: Change `elif not len(password) < 6:` to `elif len(password) < 6:`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel With `if not password.islower():` I expect it to detect if the Password I put doesnt have a lower case then print "Not a Valid Password".

Comment: still nedd help or was there already a helpful answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have done wrong in your code. That is, you are checking the whole password is lower or not, then again it is checking the whole password is upper or not. And for this reason it is always showing `not valid`. But what you need to check is, whether password contains a single lowercase character or not, a single uppercase character or not, a single digit or not and the length should be minimum 6.

For that you have to use `any()` which returns True if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False.

```
def main():
while True:
    password = input("Please enter the desired password: ")
    if not any(p.islower() for p in password): 
        print("This is NOT a valid password")
    elif not any(p.isupper() for p in password): 
        print("This is NOT a valid password")
    elif not any(p.isdigit() for p in password):
        print("This is NOT a valid password")
    elif len(password) < 6:
        print("This is NOT a valid password")
    else:
        print("This is a valid password")
        break
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `islower()`, `isupper()`, `isdigit()` check if **all** the elements of the string meet that condition. So, when you use, for example, `islower()` you are checking if all of the characters in the string are lower-case.

For this situation, I would use regular expression to check each of the criteria. with regular expressions you can customize all the rules that you want to check and it's not that difficult to learn (see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

An example of using with what you have would be

```
import re

password = input('Write a password: ')

if re.search('[A-Z]+', password) is None:
    print('invalid password!')
elif re.search('[a-z]+', password) is None:
    print('invalid password!')
elif re.search('[0-9]+', password) is None:
    print('invalid password!')
elif re.search('[' + string.punctuation + ']+', password) is None:
    print('invalid password!')
elif len(password) < 6
    print('invalid password!')
else:
    print('valid password!!')
```